# What's wrong with this query?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, i.path AS image_path 
FROM bgy_users u
LEFT JOIN bgy_images i ON i.image_id = u.image_id 
WHERE u.commentary_id = '0'
```

### Error:

**Unknown column 'u.image_id' in 'on clause'**

When there definitely is a column `image_id` in table `bgy_users`

What am I doing wrong?

**Result for `DESCRIBE BGY_USERS`**

[image]

**Result for `DESCRIBE BGY_IMAGES`**

[image]

Comment: What happens if you alias u.image_id AS users_image_id or something?

Comment: Provide the output of `DESCRIBE BGY_USERS` - if such a column exists, the error is due to a typo.

Comment: Sure that the column wasn't added afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

The query is perfectly alright mySQL 5.0.18-nt-log. Such error will be prompted only when the field does not exist, in case double check your column name image_id in bgy_users table.

Comment: Attached describe table results

Comment: if you are working in development + production environment then do check your database connection string. Again, query is okay, might be you are running correct query on a database that does not have column image_id in bgy_users table

Comment: which mySQL version you are running?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, i.path AS image_path 
FROM (bgy_users u)
LEFT JOIN (bgy_images i) ON i.image_id = u.image_id 
WHERE u.commentary_id = '0'
```

the only difference is the parenthesis around table names

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a

```
select image_id from bgy_users;
```

I am asking because the only time I have seen anything like this it has either been a code page problem or there have been non printable characters creeping into your query.

Answer (score 0):

This is real weird and the only thing I can think of is that you are querying the wrong database. Confirm in your application code that you are using correct  connection string to connect to the database.

You can also issue 'select database()' from your application to find out the name of the current database you are connected to.